# The position of finger on multitouch trackpad Macbook with JAVA

Tags: java, macos, multi-touch, touchpad

I need to detect the position of 4 finger on trackpad (macbook)
with multi-touch system

just like output following

point1 : x 20, y 30
point2 : x 30, y 40
point3 : x 40, y 50
point4 : x 50, y 60

i search on google already and i get these link
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html

https://kenai.com/projects/macmultitouch/sources/source-code-repository/content/src/com/alderstone/multitouch/mac/touchpad/tests/SwingTest.java?rev=5

but it can run able but not to detect and get position on trackpad

thank for reply

(Sorry abut my english)